# I can not change the corner color of a ScrollPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8

My css code for it looks like this yet it still doesn't work.  scrollpane?

```
.scroll-pane:corner > .viewport {

-fx-background-color : #191A19;

}
```

Is there a problem with my syntax or does the whole view port issue not allow me to edit any other aspect of the

Answer (score 8):

You css selector is wrong.

```
.scroll-pane:corner
```

selects Nodes with class "scroll-pane" which have a pseudo-class state "corner" activated. According to the [css documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane), scroll pane has no "corner" pseudoclass.

```
.scroll-pane:corner > .viewport
```

would select a node with class "viewport" that had an (immediate) parent node with class "scroll-pane" and with that parent node having the pseudoclass state "corner" activated. So, if anything, you would be selecting the viewport here.

The css you need is

```
.scroll-pane > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: #191A19 ;
}
```

Maybe have a look at a general purpose tutorial on css selectors, such as the one at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

**Update** complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScrollPaneStyledCorner extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setPrefHeight(200);
        scrollPane.setPrefWidth(200);

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(System.getProperty("javafx.version"));
        scrollPane.setContent(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("scrollPaneCorner.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

scrollPaneCorner.css:

```
.scroll-pane > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: #191A19 ;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This would be the case if i didn't have java 8 but since i have upgraded my jre to this the code that you have shown above does not work as stated in [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3538169) post made last month

Comment: This example works correctly in Java version 1.8.0_144.

Answer (score 3):

It works :

```
.corner {    
    -fx-background-color: #363636 ;
}
```