# Trouble styling ScrollPane corner color

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8

I am not able to change the color of the corner. [image]

As you can see the three white corners at the end of the scrollpanes.

```
.scroll-pane .corner  { 
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

This didn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278267/i-can-not-change-the-corner-color-of-a-scrollpane-in-javafx) or [this on the oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3538169) might be of help.

Comment: @JacobGray I'm afraid no, same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to change the filler color with this:

```
.table-view .filler{
    -fx-background-color: #fe4c58;
}
```