# Can not change the color of the corner of JavaFX WebView

Tags: javafx

I want to change the color of JavaFX WebView throught css. I tried to do it so

```
.corner {
-fx-background-color: red;
}
```

and so

```
.scroll-pane > .corner {    
-fx-background-color: red;
}
```

But all it doesn't work :( Help pls!

It is my FXMl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0"
      prefWidth="900.0" stylesheets="@../styles/Browser.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="macroapp.classes.controllers.BrowserController">
    <children>
        <AnchorPane prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="900.0" style="-fx-background-color: #17181c;">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="toMenuOfChoiceButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                        onAction="#actionToMenuOfChoice"
                        prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="42.0" text="⁞" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0"
                        AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0"/>
                    </font>
                </Button>
                <Button layoutX="57.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionToBackButton"
                        prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="59.0" styleClass="backButton" textAlignment="CENTER"
                        AnchorPane.leftAnchor="62.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="16.0"/>
                    </font>
                </Button>
                <TextField fx:id="browserTextField" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="5.0" maxWidth="700.0"
                           onKeyPressed="#keyPressedSearchTextField" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="543.0"
                           promptText=" Search..." AnchorPane.leftAnchor="131.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="17.0"/>
                    </font>
                </TextField>
                <Button fx:id="collapseButton" layoutX="744.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                        onAction="#actionCollapseButton" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="42.0" styleClass="collapseButton"
                        AnchorPane.rightAnchor="114.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0"/>
                <Button fx:id="expandOverlapButton" layoutX="796.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                        onAction="#actionExpandOverlapButton" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="42.0"
                        styleClass="expandButton" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="62.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0"/>
                <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="848.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false"
                        onAction="#actionCloseButton" prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="42.0" styleClass="closeButton"
                        AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0"/>
            </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <WebView fx:id="browserWebView" prefHeight="637.0" prefWidth="900.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets/>
            </VBox.margin>
        </WebView>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

And it is my stylesheet

```
.button {
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.backButton {
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/BackBrowser.png");
}

.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: whitesmoke;
    -fx-background-radius: 11px;
    -fx-border-radius: 11px;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: #7a7878;
    -fx-border-width: none;
}

.closeButton {
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Close.png");
}

.overlapButton {
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Overlap.png");
}

.collapseButton {
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Collapse.png");
}

.expandButton {
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-background-image: url("../resources/Expand.png");
}

.menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
}

.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-background-radius: 7px;
    -fx-border-radius: 7px;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 0.5px;
}

.menu-item .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}

.scroll-bar {
    -fx-background-color: #17181c;
}

.thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.menu-item:hover .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #4b4b4b;
}
```

It is screenshot 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoJjp.png)

IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details)))IT is more details))

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278791/230513).

Comment: @trashgod i did it, look pls.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your finding; the example I cited works correctly.

Comment: ohhh, why it doesn't work on my pc :(

Comment: I tested the example I cited on Mac OS X 10.11.6, Java version 1.8.0_144, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278267/i-can-not-change-the-corner-color-of-a-scrollpane-in-javafx/23278791#comment80259123_23278791).

Comment: @trashgod i have same version java. What is more i tried to do it even without selectors {-fx-background-color: black;}, as a result, everything was black, except for corner. I cry...

Comment: What `System.getProperty("javafx.version")` result is displayed when you run the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23278791/230513)? What platform?

Comment: @trashgod my javafx version is 8.0.112, platform is Windows 7

Comment: Hey @ProstoCoder did you solve this issue?

Comment: @user3804769 hi, as I remember, no

Comment: @ProstoCoder we solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323956/change-the-color-of-the-scrollbar-corner-in-webview?noredirect=1#comment95483362_54323956